# what can i do to resolve Oauth2Authenticantion dependency problem

Tags: java, spring-boot

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-server:unknown
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-server:jar is missing.
Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-server:jar:unknown'

```
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide more information like where you are using it or sample spring boot version which you are using

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use spring boot you can use

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
```

if you use it directly without spring boot you can use and need to mention the version in that case

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
```